# Delete a HTML canvas Line

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the live demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/NWXvVEm?editors=1111) I have a grid here and I draw a ctx line on the grid. May I know how to **remove** the ctx line using a button?

[image: My Canvas Here]

In my JS code,

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(350, 110);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You've to clear the canvas, and re-draw everything except the line you want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a line (or any other shape) from the canvas, but you can re-draw the entire thing. You then need to be able to maintain the "state" of the canvas. In this example I have an array of objects that represent individual lines. When the `draw()` function is called, the lines are also drawn on the canvas.

There are two functions to illustrate how you can change the state by removing lines or adding new lines. So, depending on how the user should interact with the canvas you would add and remove these lines/objects from the array.

### Update

The style of the line can be changed using `strokeStyle` and `lineWidth`. These are applied on `stroke()`. For each stroke you need to stat a new path with `beginPath()`. In the beginnig and end of `draw()` I added `save()` and `restore()`. `save()` saves the current state (kind of the initial state, here) and `restore()` reverts back to that state.

```js
var lines = [{
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 300,
    y2: 110
  },
  {
    x1: 10,
    y1: 10,
    x2: 350,
    y2: 110
  }
];
var canvas, context;

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
if (canvas.getContext) {
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  draw(); // intitial draw
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.save();
  context.strokeStyle = 'grey';
  context.beginPath();
  for (var x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 50) {
    context.moveTo(x, 0);
    context.lineTo(x, 500);
  }
  for (var y = 0.5; y < 500; y += 50) {
    context.moveTo(0, y);
    context.lineTo(500, y);
  }
  context.stroke();
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.beginPath();
  // draw alle the lines
  lines.forEach(line => {
    context.moveTo(line.x1, line.y1);
    context.lineTo(line.x2, line.y2);
  });
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function removeline(){
  lines.shift();
  draw(); // re-draw the canvas
}

function addline(){
  let line = {
    x1: Math.random()*500,
    y1: Math.random()*500,
    x2: Math.random()*500,
    y2: Math.random()*500
  };
  lines.push(line);
  draw(); // re-draw the canvas
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="removeline()">Remove line</button>
  <button onclick="addline()">Add line</button>
</div>
<canvas id='canvas' width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi sir,sorry to bother,  I have updated the code at the same link I posted above and you can click on the grid to play around. My attempt to make the grid and lines drawn to be of different colour seems to fail. I change the  colur in context.strokeStyle bit its not working because I believe that the context is declared the same 2 times?